# Sequel Ace failing to connect to MySQL via SSH

Tags: ssh, sequelace

I'm trying to migrate from Sequel Pro to Sequel Ace because I'm about to upgrade a MySQL server from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0

[The documentation on migrating settings and favourites](https://sequel-ace.com/get-started/migrating-from-sequel-pro.html) was helpful, but Sequel Ace is not able to connect to the server using the same details as Sequel Pro.

Is anyone able to make an educated guess why this is failing in Sequel Ace but not Sequel Pro by looking at error output that Sequel Ace shows from OpenSSH?

```
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Applications/Sequel Ace.app/Contents/Resources/ssh_config
debug1: /Applications/Sequel Ace.app/Contents/Resources/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to REDACTED port 22.
debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/REDACTED/.keys/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/REDACTED/.keys/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.9
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to REDACTED:22 as 'REDACTED'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:XHJJUykh+CMmszPSY+hp8nkdNLxiS17RcVIxC01UnRw
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'REDACTED' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/REDACTED/Library/Containers/com.sequel-ace.sequel-ace/Data/.keys/ssh_known_hosts_strict:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_get_authentication_socket: Operation not permitted
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/REDACTED/.keys/id_rsa  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/REDACTED/.keys/id_rsa
no such identity: /Users/REDACTED/.keys/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
REDACTED@REDACTED: Permission denied (publickey).
The SSH Tunnel could not authenticate with the remote host. Please check your password and ensure you still have access.
```

Comment: According to the logs there is an issue with ssh operations, not with mysql.

Comment: Using SSH -- Looks like it tries a public key and gets denied, and when trying a private key, there is no key *"No such file or directory*" --  I am assuming the public key/pair is mismatched.

Comment: @Zak : curious, the other MySQL client apps that I have on this Mac are happy using the same SSH details to connect to this server. Thanks for your input!